# JS switch statement inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem. I saw a possible solution but it doesn't work for me. I need to put a `switch` statement inside function because I have a lot of cases to change.

Switch function:

```
var filter = function(value) {
    switch(typeof value) {
    case 'number is required':
        value = 'Number field is required!';
        break;
    }
}
```

And i call this function inside AJAX

```
$.map(response.errors, function(e){
     filter(e) // I tried this and
     filter = e;
     // my code to put here in DIV.  
 })
```

Error message returns the case that I want to change. e.g: `<div class="alert alert-success">number is required</div>`;

Comment: As far as I know, `typeof value` will never return "number is required"

Comment: Why are you using 'typeof value'. typeof is always going to be one of the following ("undefined", "object", "boolean", "string", "number", "symbol", "function"). Your case of 'number is required' is never going to match your switch statement.

Comment: You're also missing the `:` after the case value.

Comment: Yes, is returning that. response errors return an object(Object {53077: "number is required."}) and I want to change the returned value to become more "compressible".

Comment: @Barmar My code have a lot of values, i rewrite a example, so I don't forgot the `:`

Comment: Why are you reassigning the function name with `filter = e;`?

Comment: @Barmar I really don't know. I'm learning JS =/

Comment: I think what you want is `msg = filter(e);`, and then put `msg` into the DIV. `filter` needs to use a `return` statement to return something.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Do you want to switch on the value of `value`, or on what type it is (string, number, object)?

Comment: A callback to a `.map()` function should return a value.  Other than that, I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're doing, but I suspect it's something like this:

```
function filter(value) {
    switch (value) {
    case 'number is required':
        value = 'Number field is required';
        break;
    case 'something else':
        value = 'Some other message';
        break;
    // More cases here
    }
    return value;
}

$.each(response.errors, function(i, e) {
    msg = filter(e);
    $("#errors").append("<div class='error-msg'>" + msg + "</div>");
});
```

The `filter` function returns the replacement message if it matches one of the cases. The caller assigns this return value to a variable, and puts it into the DIV.

Instead of a `case`, you can also use an object as a dictionary, which is my preferred method:

```
var translations = {
    'number is required': 'Number field is required',
    'something else': 'Some other message',
    // more cases here
};
function filter(value) {
    return translations[value] || value;
}
```

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssss bro!!! You're awesome, this worked! And thanks for the second method, really looks good!

Comment: OP, you should really avoid the use of "filter" here. The terms "map", "filter" and "reduce" all have [specific meanings in functional programming](http://redsymbol.net/articles/crash-course-applied-functional-programming/). What you are doing here is generally called a "lookup".